# Запятая перед ‘из-за’

Tags: пунктуация

Сомневаюсь, точно ли не нужна запятая.

Таиланд в летние месяцы — непопулярное направление (,) из-за того, что здесь часты в это время тропические ливни.

Comment: Нужна. А вот вторая запятая не нужна. Только "часты" и "в это время" лучше поменять местами.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сказать так:

**Таиланд в летние месяцы — непопулярное направление, так как  здесь часты в это время тропические ливни.**

Или так (но это "длиннее" и неудобнее для произношения): **Таиланд в летние месяцы — непопулярное направление, потому что  здесь часты в это время тропические ливни.**

Другой вариант: **Таиланд в летние месяцы — непопулярное направление, так как в это время  здесь часто   бывают тропические ливни.**

**Пояснение**

1) **Расчленять союз в данном случае нежелательно,** так как при расчленении отношения между главным и придаточным предложением становятся **взаимообусловленными**, в то время как без расчленения (в постпозиции) это **чисто причинное** значение придаточного.

Здесь логичнее и удобнее в смысловом отношении **сначала указать**, что Таиланд в летние месяцы — непопулярное направление, а уже **потом назвать причину.**

2) Союз ***из-за того что*** обычно используется в расчлененном виде: *Он обиделся из-за того, что я его не пригласил.*

Comment: То есть Вы считаете, что споры о запятой в авторском варианте контрпродуктивны, так как это плохой вариант? Понял ли я Вас правильно?

Comment: У приведенного варианта есть недостатки. 1) Союз "из-за того что" желательно не расчленять (причины указаны). 2) В нерасчлененном состоянии он длинен, да еще содержит сложный союз из-за,  а речь (как письменная, так и устная) должна стремиться к краткой форме, особенно в информационных текстах.

Comment: Из-за – не "сложный союз", а предлог. "В нерасчлененном состоянии он длинен, а речь должна стремиться к краткой форме" – ну, это перл. Ни прибавить, ни убавить.

Comment: Текст исправлен.
У приведенного варианта есть недостатки. 1) Союз "из-за того что" желательно не расчленять (причины указаны). 2) В нерасчлененном состоянии он длинен, да еще содержит сложный предлог из-за, а речь (как письменная, так и устная) должна быть по возможности краткой, особенно в информационных текстах.

Comment: ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ. Спасибо за исправление. Про речь могу добавить следующее. Основное требование информативного стиля состоит в том, что  нужно кратко, интересно и убедительно передать максимум информации, если мы уважаем нашего читателя.  Это из книги «Пиши, сокращай. Как создавать сильный текст». Также предложение должно быть удобным для произношения, в частности,  желательно, чтобы его отдельные части (фразы)   имели  оптимальную и примерно равную  длину, если они разделены запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, при таком построении предложения вырисовывается присоединительная конструкция (некие дополнительные разъяснения), которая должна отделяться запятой или тире. Но поскольку тире уже употреблено в этом предложении, то ставим запятую. Вторая запятая ставится как часть союза «из-за того, что»

> [ИЗ-ЗА ТОГО, ЧТО](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_821), союз
>   Придаточные предложения, присоединяемые союзом «из-за того, что», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми. При этом первая запятая обычно ставится не перед союзом, а между его частями (перед словом «что»).

Сравните:

*Таиланд в летние месяцы — направление непопулярное из-за того, что здесь часты в это время тропические ливни.*

"Непопулярное из-за того, что..." Нет присоединительного значения.

Comment: Какая присоединительная конструкция?! Обычное СПП, зачем сбивать с толку? Запятая требуется одна – перед союзом. В определенном контексте (если имеется упор на разъяснение, почему именно непопулярное) – можно расчленить союз, но тогда первая запятая не нужна. Элементарные же вещи...

Comment: @Niemand, По-моему, нужно либо признать порядок слов неверным, либо считать это присоединительной конструкцией. Заметьте, если изменить порядок слов, то имеем обычное СПП.